# Assertion Error, error when there shouldn't be one

Tags: python, python-3.x, assertion

```
try:
    guess = str(int(input("Please enter your guess: ")))
    assert len(guess) == 4
except ValueError or AssertionError:
    print("Please enter a 4 digit number as your guess not a word or a different digit number. ")
```

Assertion Error Received when I type a number that is not 4 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`except ValueError or AssertionError:` should be `except (ValueError, AssertionError):`

When you do `or` you are not catching the exception `AssertionError`

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze a code structure. I've added parenthesis to denote how Python 
interpreter groups statements.

```
try:
    do_something()
except (ValueError or AssertionError):
    handle_error()
```

Let's check what happens to definition of exception to catch. Quoting [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=conditional#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

"If `x` is true" actually refers to `x` being true in boolean context (value of `x.`[`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__)`()` in Python 2, `x.`[`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__)`()` in Python 3). All objects (including classes) are implicitly truthy, unless implemented otherwise.

```
# No exception is raised in either case
assert ValueError
assert AssertionError
# both values after conversion are True
assert bool(ValueError) is True
assert bool(AssertionError) is True
```

After taking in consideration boolean context of classes and quoted docs about boolean operations, we may safely asssume that `(ValueError or AssertionError)` evaluates to `ValueError`.

To catch multiple exception you need to put them in tuple:

```
try:
    do_something()
except (ValueError, AssertionError):
    handle_error()
```